# Why do some programs require a restart after install?

Tags: installation, updates, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I need restart computer after installing new software?](https://superuser.com/questions/171590/why-do-i-need-restart-computer-after-installing-new-software)

I've been annoyed by this for some time now.  I install or update a program and it requires a restart?!

Come culprit programs:

- IE 9
- iTunes
- Safari

My issue is, that most of these can't be making that many more changes to the system as thier counterparts that DONT require a restart:

- chrome
- firefox
- winamp
- vlc
- etc

I can understand major system updates to the OS and driver updates, and therefore I'm talking solely on third party software.  So what's the deal?  Why do some programs require a restart while others don't?