# Which characteristic have an aplication instalation that must reboot computer after installed?

Tags: windows, installation, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I need restart computer after installing new software?](https://superuser.com/questions/171590/why-do-i-need-restart-computer-after-installing-new-software)

There are some applications that after its installation you must reboot your Windows in order to functioning. There are another ones (sometimes with the same functionality) that don't force you to reboot. 
I know that there are some applications that works with driver loading, so the system must be rebooted to makes the new application funcional. However I can't see for specific software features beyond this to force me to restart my system. 
So, my question is... What are the requirements or the features of an application that makes it a "must-reboot-application" after installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboots are required to clear file locking issues, either for drivers or within the software itself. This is why many installations (and updates) request that you close down all other running applications before continuing.

There are also many installation packages which don't actually require a reboot but request one just to be on the safe side. That is really up to the company that packages the software.

Comment: In other words, you've confirmed my suspicions -- some developers actually *do* just throw that in to be annoying. ;-)

Comment: No, the being annoying is just a bonus side benefit. They throw it in because they don't know any better.