# How do I reload windows without rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, reboot

I was wondering, is it possible to reload all the files in windows without rebooting the system to save time like when you install a new program and it asked you to reboot your PC, but instead I want to be able to reload windows like rebooting but with out shutting down the computer because it takes forever.

Comment: If there is a way that would be nice. But I think the computer reboots for a reason...

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/171590/why-do-i-need-restart-computer-after-installing-new-software

Comment: And you would be on.. what version of windows?

Answer (score -1):

use taskmanager and to processes tab and scroll to explorer.exe, click on it  and select end process tree,wait for desktop background and click on file on the taskmgr and click new task  and type explorer.exe again with extension